# How to change default program for open pdf file in firefox?

Tags: firefox, pdf

When I download a file in Firefox, I want the default program that display in **open with** section to change to nitro or adobe reader.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Go to ☰ -> Options -> Applications -> Search for the PDF type and set to "Always Ask" and under the software you want to open with. See the attached picture below.

[image]

Comment: I install adobe reader on my computer but don't appeared in blow of Always ask option.

Comment: It should appear below the three action options like in the picture, if not try "Use other..." and select it from the list or in best case restart Firefox.

Comment: Try reinstalling, it should appear there if installed correctly. Make sure you close and re-open Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Right click a pdf file and change open with adobe then it will automatically reflect in your browser also.

[image: Properties]

Answer (score 1):

I select default program such as this image .I select in image number 3 .exe file of pdf reader and click on the ok then it solved.

Thank you for answering.

[image]